# Woocommerce - Custom Shortcode - Add to Cart Button - How?

Tags: woocommerce, shortcode

I am working a custom loop for Woocommerce. It is defined as shortcode.
My code looks like this:

```
<?php add_shortcode( 'kurse', 'ik_kurse' );
function ik_kurse( $atts, $content = null ) {

// Get shortcode parameters
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    "per_page" => ''
), $atts));

// Get WooCommerce Global
global $woocommerce;


// Create the object
ob_start();


// Create query arguments array
$query_args = array(
                'posts_per_page' => '', 
                'no_found_rows'  => 1, 
                'post_status'    => 'publish', 
                'post_type'      => 'product', 
                );

// Add meta_query to query args
$query_args['meta_query'] = array();

// Check products stock status
$query_args['meta_query'][] = $woocommerce->query->stock_status_meta_query();

// Create a new query
$r = new WP_Query($query_args);

// If query return results
if ( $r->have_posts() ) {

    $content = '<ul class="rc_wc_rvp_product_list_widget">';

    // Start the loop
    while ( $r->have_posts()) {
        $r->the_post();
        global $product;
        $description=  $prod_term->description;
        $content .= '***ADD TO CART BUTTON';
        $content .= '<li>';
        $content .= $product->get_sku(); ?> <br /><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt );
        $content .= " | ";
        $content .= $product->get_price_html();
        $content .= '</li>';


    }

    $content .= '</ul>';

}

// Get clean object
$content .= ob_get_clean();

// Return whole content
return $content;}
```

I can not figure out how to add the "Add to Cart" Button here, so it is in line for every single product. Can someone help? Thank you!

Comment: Can you clarify "so it is in line for every single product"?

Comment: [Product 1]  Add to Cart | Short Description | Price [Line Break]



[Product 2]  Add to Cart | Short Description | Price [Line Break]



[Product 3]  Add to Cart | Short Description | Price [Line Break]

Something like this.

Comment: And what are you seeing now? This sounds like a CSS issue and you will need to apply the desired styling to the `li` element in your list.

Comment: I see:
[Product 1]  Short Description | Price [Line Break]  
[Product 2]  Short Description | Price [Line Break]  
[Product 3] | Short Description | Price [Line Break]  
[Product 1] Add to Cart 1[ Line Break]  
[Product 2] Add to Cart 2[ Line Break]  
[Product 3] Add to Cart 3[ Line Break]